# Get Not Null Values in Wrapped Array

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, qubole

I have a Wrapped Array and want to only get the Non Null values when I query with **LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE**. I also tried **IS NOT NULL** but that does not return anything.

SAMPLE STRUCTURE:

**COLUMNNAME: theARRAY**

```
WrappedArray([null,theVal,tags,[null,null,7298,null,null,null],false])
```

schema is

```
array<struct<id:string,name:string,type:string,value:struct<member0:string,member1:bigint,member2:int,member3:double,member4:float,member5:boolean>,shouldIndex:boolean>>
```

My Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT revs
FROM events 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(theARRAY.value.member2) theTab2 AS revs
```

My result:

```
__________
|**revs**|
__________
|7298    |
__________
| null   |
__________
```

WHen is use the **IS NOT NULL**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT revs
FROM events 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(theARRAY.value.member2) theTab2 AS revs 
revs IS NOT NULL
```

nothing gets returned.

I need:

```
|**revs**|
__________
|7298    |
__________
```

How can fix my query to get the result as above?

Answer (score 1):

You can refine the query as:

```
SELECT revs FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT revs 'revs' 
FROM events 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(theARRAY.value.member2) theTab2 AS revs 
) WHERE revs IS NOT NULL
```